# cookies won't delete

Tags: php

Here is my login cookies being set

```
setcookie('username[0]',$username,time()+(60*60*24*365));
setcookie('username[1]',$userid,time()+(60*60*24*365));
setcookie('username[2]',$subscribed,time()+(60*60*24*365));         
setcookie('password',md5($password),time()+(60*60*24*365));
setcookie('admin',$admin,time()+(60*60*24*365));
```

Here is my logout function

```
function logout($return) {

         setcookie('username[0]', '', time()-(60*60*24*365));
    setcookie('username[1]', '', time()-(60*60*24*365));
    setcookie('username[2]', '', time()-(60*60*24*365));
    setcookie('password', '', time()-(60*60*24*365));
    setcookie('admin', '', time()-(60*60*24*365));


      header( 'Location: ' . $return );

    echo "<div class='fontall'><span class='fontdif'>You've been logged out.  </span><a href='$return'>Click Here</a><span class='fontdif' to return</span></div>";

        }
```

When i try to log out and return to the page i am still logged in? What did i do wrong?

Comment: yes and the page is still logged in.

Comment: when i log out i get the  'cannot modify headers' error?

Comment: That's because you output _something_ before you (re)set the cookies. A good way to prevent that is to make sure you first gather all information, and then worry about how it should be sent back to the browser.

Answer (score 4):

If you got the 'cannot modify headers' error, it means you echo out something before `setcookie`. `setcookie` must do before any content echo out.

> Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your
>   script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place
>   calls to this function prior to any output, including  and
>    tags as well as any whitespace.

Comment: I have my logout code in a function.  So i shouldn't put my logout code in a function? Just put the code on a blank page.

Comment: @user892134 It doesn't matter, just make sure nothing is echo out before setcookie.

Comment: Check my edit, i'm not echo'ing anything before setcookie and i still get this error.

Comment: But where are you calling your logout() from?  Is there any echo, print, or HTML-mode output before that?  You can also check by viewing source and seeing what is before that error.

Comment: i've solved the 'cannot modify headers' problem and it still doesn't delete the cookies?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // 1. Find the session
    session_start();

    // 2. Unset all the session variables
    $_SESSION = array();

    // 3. Destroy the session cookie
    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
    }

    // 4. Destroy the session
    session_destroy();
```

That should work.
Probably..u didn't destroy the session?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the code - they should be deleting the cookies. Are you sure that the cookies are not deleting? After you logout, try checking if the cookies exist. You may do so using the browser that show the active cookies. Or alternatively you may try reading the cookies using PHP.

Second, how are you checking if the session is still valid? Can you please share that piece of code? And where do you check your session - do you do them on all pages?